# Will running jQuery.get too often cause performance issues for the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, websocket

So you understand what I'm trying to do, I've written a web page which shows events logged in MySQL as soon as they are inserted into the database (basically monitoring Windows & Mac logon/logoff on the network). Every time a new event is inserted the PHP script connects to a web socket and sends a message to all connected browsers to notify them of the new event. When the browsers receive the notification message they run `jQuery.get("liveeventsearch.php", ...);` to fetch the new event from the database (see javascript code below).

In a nutshell, when a web socket message is received fetch the new record from the database, append the result to a table and play a notification sound.

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
    if (msg.data == "@all new event") {
        var newLastUpdate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
        jQuery.get("liveeventsearch.php", <?php echo '{ Key:"' . $Value . '", etc... , lastupdate:lastUpdate }'; ?>, function(result) {
            jQuery('#LiveResults tbody').append(result);
            if (jQuery('#chkNotification-Audio').is(':checked') && result > "")
            {
                jQuery("#Notification-Audio").trigger("play");
            }
            lastUpdate = newLastUpdate;
        });
    }
};
```

My concern is that there are currently approx 1200 devices on the network and it is expected that most, if not all of them will logon/logoff within a 5 to 10 minute period in large clumps hourly with a few additional scattered here and there. So the browser (depending on the supplied search criteria) will likely receive a large number of web socket messages in a small period of time, if not simultaneously (and obviously fetch `liveeventsearch.php` that many times). Is this likely to cause a problem for the browser fetching results so frequently?

I can provide the code in `liveeventsearch.php` if necessary.

**Alternate Methods**

I had thought about adding something like this in the `socket.onmessage` function to reduce the frequency.

```
//[PSEUDO CODE]
if (currentTime > lastUpdate + 3 seconds)
{
    jQuery.get(...);
}
```

But then the last set of events will not appear until another web socket message is received which could be a lot longer than 3 seconds. I could possibly use a timer instead, but that kind of defeats the object of having a web socket providing 'live' updates.

---

Another option I thought of is to create a new MySQL table (e.g. `liveUpdates`) which contains only an `ID` field. Then run a cron job every X seconds which inserts a new ID in that table (or run a a script on the server with a continuous loop doing the same thing?). My `events` table could then have an additional field tying each event to the latest `liveUpdates.ID` and the cron job could send the web socket message each time a new update ID was created instead of every time an event is logged. But this again would have the same effect as using a timer.

Comment: seems weird the websocket does not just give the information needed that you have to make another request,

Comment: The issue is not the browser here, in reality the issue is can your server handle the load of requests.

Comment: Thats a really weird way of doing things. The point of websockets is to avoid the need for AJAX polling. Just put the new record in to the message sent through the socket.

Comment: And hopefully you realize the php code you are using for the GET request will be the same data everytime.

Comment: @epascarello The web socket just triggers socket.onmessage function which sends `lastUpdate` to the PHP script. The PHP script then runs a SQL statement looking for any records after that time. Your point about the server handling the requests is a good question.

@RoryMcCrossan That seems like a much simpler solution. I've no idea why I've over complicated it and not just done what you've suggested lol.

Comment: You could `dequeue` the onmessage.  Frequently used for mouse events, a basic implementation would be: you get a message then call `setTimeout` - if you get another message before the timeout completes, you `clearTimeout` the original and set a new one.

Comment: @epascarello They GET request sends the same data which contains the search criteria, BUT the last parameter is `lastUpdate` which is a javascript variable.

Comment: You could also use an ajax-queue - i.e make one call then disable any other calls until the first has completed (storing if a new call is needed when the first completes).

Comment: Doing simple math, considering a 10 min = 600 secs time frame, it will result in an average of 2 signals/sec, so it seems to be not heavy at all.

Comment: @CarlosMora The network is in an educational environment. So we generally have everybody log off at the end of a lesson, then there's a small break and then everybody logs on at the start of the next lesson. This would repeat hourly. If I removed the jQuery.get and just passed the data in the web socket message reducing the load slightly do you still think this would not be too heavy?

Comment: @Daniel Sth that I would like to know is the process that pushes messages. It can be a good point to pace down the message volume. It is pusher's environment the most certain and well known, you can tell how fast clients are, so i would prefer to delegate that matter to the pusher.